# How to keep Global.asax from being compiled into the app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, global-asax

Working with a MVC3/.NET Framework4/IIS7.5 app that in previous deployments has included the Gobal.asax.cs copied to the server. Some setting or configuration has changed that behavior now to include just the Global.asax with none of the codebehind included. The properties setting shows Copy Always | BuildAction Content which is, I think, what it should be.

I'm deploying via FileSystem (a vpn connection to my remote host) because I presume that to be the fewest deployment hoops - I know from my point of view it's preferable to the alternate deployment methods.

Is that having an effect on how Global.asax is being treated - where else should I be looking?

thx

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to deploy the `Gobal.asax.cs` file to your server?

Comment: I know it violates some level of best practices but I find it convenient to store and edit some bits of app and session code there without need to recompile / redeploy.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2012 I was able to produce a published build on my local file system which included `Global.asax.cs` by setting the `Build Action` and `Copy to Output Directory` properties of the `Global.asax.cs` file to:

```
Build Action             : Content
Copy to Output Directory : Copy always
```

I suspect you've only set these property values on the `Global.asax` file.

This was performed on an ASP.NET MVC3 C# project.